# Create directory, enter it, build html file

Tags: php

I want to be able to assemble a directory with PHP then enter that directory then recreate my html file.

The problem I have is that after the directory is built, I want to enter it then assemble the html file, but it makes the directory then it just places the html file outside.

Is there a way to navigate into the created directory?

```
<?php
$name  = htmlspecialchars( $_POST['name'] );
$redirect   = htmlspecialchars( $_POST['redirect'] );
$appid   = htmlspecialchars( $_POST['appid'] );
$thisdir = getcwd(); 
$new_dir = '145';

$html = <<<EOT
<div class="test">$appid</div>
EOT;

if(mkdir("testdir/" . $newdir, 0777)){
   echo "Directory has been created successfully...";
   $myFile = "!" . '.html';
   file_put_contents( $myFile, $html );
} else {
echo "Failed to create directory...";
} 
?>
```

Comment: Add the path to the new directory to your file_put_contents. Also $newdir is not $new_dir

Comment: Kind of a *facepalm* there. @JayBlanchard Evenin' Sam

Comment: Yeppers @Fred-ii- *Evenin' Ralph*

Comment: Watch out @Fred-ii-! The long-toothed ones are about!

Comment: @JayBlanchard I've already made provisions for that without even knowing. Cooked a ham with plenty of garlic.

Comment: @JayBlanchard *Meh...*, maybe the OP will *"see the light"* and say *"Hey Jay, thanks man. Make that an answer and I'll accept it!"*. Seeing the difference in timestamps and all ;-) That's "if" integrity is really at work in this era.

Comment: Tu es une des personne les plus intègres que je connais mon ami ;-) @JayBlanchard Have a great evening buddy, *cheers!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `$new_dir` to `$newdir`  and add the dir name before the filename:

```
$newdir = '145';
if(mkdir("testdir/" . $newdir, 0777)){
echo "Directory has been created successfully...";
$myFile = "!" . '.html';
    file_put_contents( "testdir/$newdir/$myFile", $html );
} else {
     echo "Failed to create directory...";
}
```

---

Note:

Append `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');` at the top of your script to enable error reporting so you can see what's wrong with your code.

Comment: You edited your comment, it didn't contain  `Add the path to the new directory `. Next time, instead of proving an incomplete comment, write a proper answer.

Comment: I didn't copy anything from you. What makes you think you're the only one to see the error? Also, is there any SO rule that doesn't allow to copy part of a comment and make it a clean answer? Come on jay, you're making this something bigger than actually is